# How to add a datepicker in magento 1.9 ( date picker within serialized_array)

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-field

[image]

> app/code/local/Companyname/Deliverydate/Block/Adminhtml/Mappingdate.php

```
<?php

class Companyname_Deliverydate_Block_Adminhtml_Mappingdate  
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Array_Abstract
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('deliverydate');
        $dateFormat = Mage::app()->getLocale()- 
        >getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);
        $this->addColumn( 'date', array(
          'name'   => 'date',
          'label'  => $helper->__('Date'),
          'image'  => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
          'input_format' => Varien_Date::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
          'value' => date('d/m/Y'),
          'format'       => $dateFormat
     )); 

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

> system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <bootsgrid translate="label" module="deliverydate">
            <label>Bootsgrid</label>
            <sort_order>400</sort_order>
        </bootsgrid>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <deliverydate translate="label" module="deliverydate">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Delivery Date</label>
            <tab>bootsgrid</tab>
            <sort_order>130</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <deliverydate_general translate="label">
                    <label>General</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Select Yes to enable this feature.</comment>
                        </enabled>
                        <!-- <on_which_page translate="label">
                            <label>Show on?</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>Bootsgrid_Deliverydate_Model_Config_Option</source_model>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Choose at which step delivery date should be captured.</comment>
                        </on_which_page> -->
<!--                         <deliverydate_html translate="label">
                            <label>Design HTML</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment></comment>
                        </deliverydate_html>
 -->                        <deliverydate_format>
                            <label>Date Format</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>Bootsgrid_Deliverydate_Model_Config_Dateformat</source_model>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Choose date format in which date will be displayed in frontend and admin panel.</comment>
                        </deliverydate_format>
                        <!-- <deliverytime_format>
                            <label>Time Format</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>Bootsgrid_Deliverydate_Model_Config_Timeformat</source_model>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Choose time format in which time will be displayed in frontend and admin panel.</comment>
                        </deliverytime_format> -->
                        <deliverydate_dayoff>
                            <label>Day Off</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>Bootsgrid_Deliverydate_Model_Config_Dayoff</source_model>
                            <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Choose days on which shipping will not be available.</comment>
                        </deliverydate_dayoff>
                        <mapping_date>
                            <label>Date Off</label>
                            <frontend_model>deliverydate/adminhtml_mappingdate</frontend_model>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>   <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </mapping_date>
                    </fields>
                </deliverydate_general>
            </groups>
        </deliverydate>
    </sections>
</config>
```

[Refered this](http://deliverydate.demo.aheadworks.com/index.php/admin/system_config/index/key/fb0b61ab7e69a2426c60ce6b0041a9fe/)

[image]

Comment: Try following solution https://magecomp.com/blog/add-date-time-picker-in-magento-system-configuration/ Please let me know still issue not fixed.

Comment: I was tried an above link  output came normal input date - https://prnt.sc/mw51sc but i need  a datepicker  with serialized array

Comment: you can check here dropdown field add here you are using `Mage_Core_Block_Html_Date `

Comment: I will try and update  you -@rakesh

Answer (score 1):

**To add date & time picker, first of all you need to create date.php file at following location in your custom extension**

**[Vendor][ModuleName]\ Block\Adminhtml\System\Config**

```
<?php
class [Vendor]\[ModuleName]\ Block\Adminhtml\System\Config \date extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
                protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $date = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date;
        $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM);

        $data = array(
            'name'      => $element->getName(),
            'html_id'   => $element->getId(),
            'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        );
        $date->setData($data);
        $date->setValue($element->getValue(), $format);
        $date->setFormat(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM));
        $date->setClass($element->getFieldConfig()->validate->asArray());
        $date->setForm($element->getForm());

        return $date->getElementHtml();
    }
}
?>
```

**Once you have created date.php file, you have to add below code in System.xml file.**

```
<startdate translate="label">
<label>Offer Start Date</label>
<frontend_model>notificationbar/adminhtml_system_config_date</frontend_model>
<backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array</backend_model>
<sort_order>150</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</startdate>
<starttime translate="label comment">
<label>Offer Start Time</label>
 <frontend_type>time</frontend_type>
<sort_order>152</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
 <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</starttime>
```

Comment: your answer is support for normal datepicker  but i need a date picker within serialized array

Comment: Define <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array</backend_model> in system.xml file

Comment: adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array is use as serialized array.

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: I already tried that way its reflects output https://prnt.sc/mw5rcj  - @Ronak