# Magento 2 : How to avoid 302 status code, actually Referrer URL returns 302 status code?

Tags: magento2, redirect-url

If anyone have idea please guide me, below is my code:

```
<?php
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 
    class Xyz extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
        ) {

        parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute()
        {   

                $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
                $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
                return $resultRedirect;
                // $this->_redirect->getRefererUrl() -> return with 302 status code
        }
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context; 
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 
    class Xyz extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        protected $redirect;
        public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
        ) 
        {

        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute()
        {   
            $redirectUrl = $this->redirect->getRedirectUrl();
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($redirectUrl);
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
}
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: still it is coming with 302 status code

Comment: It works in me the above code

Comment: can you tell me what is really the logic you need? because you can actually avoid 302 status by changing redirect to TYPE_PAGE

Comment: like this `public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
        return $resultRedirect;
    }`

Comment: i am redirecting to the previous page url with error message this time it should display 200 status code in network for browser but its redirecting with 302 status code and its working fine.

Comment: I see, you just need to add this line `$resultRedirect->setHttpResponseCode(301);` on top of `$resultRedirect->setUrl($redirectUrl);` and should not return a 302 status code. Please try and check

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way using setRedirect an code 301:

```
public function execute()
{   
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl(), 301);
    return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
}
```

Comment: can u please help me solve [this issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265121/how-to-add-a-datepicker-in-magento-1-9-date-picker-within-serialized-array) @HelgeB