# Magento 2.3 Advanced search giving 404

Tags: search, magento2.3, 404

I would like to use the advanced search on my home page,  it works fine if I click the advanced search link in the footer at the bottom. But if I add

```
{{block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::advanced/form.phtml"}}
```

to my home page, the search results are all 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve  your request like this way

You get the issue like 404 because of the form post URL  of home page advanced search is : `www.example.com/cms/index/result` which is a 404 page at Magento.

And form  Post URL defined at `getSearchPostUrl()`

```
 public function getSearchPostUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/result');
    }
```

***So you have to change it to full URL***

```
 public function getSearchPostUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result');
    }
```

So, you have to create  [a plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) at on this method which change url to `$this->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result');`

Create a custom module  and define  plugin at `di.xml` `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc/frontend`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form">
        <plugin name="change_post_url" sortOrder="1"
                type="{Vendor}\{Modulename}\Plugin\FormPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin class located at `FormPlugin.php` `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/Plugin/`

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename}\Plugin;

class FormPlugin
{

    public function afterGetSearchPostUrl(\Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form $subject, $result)
    {
        return $subject->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result');
    }
}
```

**Also, this module should have:**

1. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc/module.xml`.
2. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/composer.json`
3. . `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/registration.php`.

**After do module enabled and setup upgrade, Di compile, Static content deploy**
**After adding the event you should  flush the cache.**

The Module structure will  like

[image]

Comment: can u please help me to solve [this issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265121/how-to-add-a-datepicker-in-magento-1-9-date-picker-within-serialized-array) @amit bera

Comment: Hi Amit, Thanks for your detailed reply, i have followed what you said but i get the following error 
[code]user@server:~/public_html$ bin/magento module:enable cjp_homepagesearch


  There are no commands defined in the "module" namespace.
[/code]

Comment: Probably more help if i give a link to the files i have created [link]http://test.maritimebooks.co.uk/colinmodule.tar.gz

Comment: your module structure is wrong. please study Magento  structure

Comment: Code is give at https://github.com/devamitbera/magento-stackexchange/blob/master/265323.zip

Comment: Hi Amit :) 
Thanks for your help im a bit stuck on the di:complie bit
 Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Cjp\Homepagesearch\Plugin\FormPlugin\Form, because the name is already in use in /home/devsite/public_html/app/code/Cjp/Homepagesearch/Plugin/FormPlugin.php on line 4

i removed the line and then got this error

Compilation was started.
Interceptors generation... 4/7 [=======>-----]  57% 26 secs 213.0 MiBPHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in /home/devsite/public_html/app/code/Cjp/Homepagesearch/Plugin/FormPlugin.php on line 7

Comment: Plugin  class namespace is wrong `<?php
namespace Cjp\Homepagesearch\Plugin;

class FormPlugin
{

    public function afterGetSearchPostUrl(
        \Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        return $subject->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result');
    }
}
`

Comment: after that do di compile

Comment: You Sir, are an absolute gentleman,

Thank you so much for all your help :D